# Issue comparing two exploded php arrays to find overlap

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, explode, array-intersect

I'm comparing the results of two exploded strings (results from a query), though when I use array_intersect to find the overlap of the arrays, I unfortunately only receive the overlap of those tags which are come first in each array...so for example if two arrays look like this:

Array1:

```
array(
  [0]=> tag_a
  [1]=> tag_b
)
```

Array2:

```
array(
  [0]=> tag_a
  [1]=> tag_b
)
```

Array_Intersect is only returning **tag_a** as a match. I expected the behavior of array_intersect to return tag_a as well as tab_b.

As you can see later in my code, I'm then using the matches (tags present in both arrays) to build the array **contactarray**. I'm able to build the array OK, it just doesn't contain the values I would have expected (ex: tag_b).

EDIT I've run several tests printing the contactarray and have applied various tag strings to those contacts and only the contacts who have have tag_a first (in the array) are being returned even though several other contacts have tag_a, though it's just not first in the array.
Thoughts?

```
if ($frequency == 'Weekly')
{
  $data['query_tag'] = $this->db->get('tags');

  foreach ($data['query_tag']->result() as $row2)
  {
    $contact_tags = $row2->tags;
    $contact_tags_exploded = explode(",", $contact_tags);

    $rule_tags_exploded = explode(",", $rule_tags);
    $result = array_intersect($rule_tags_exploded, $contact_tags_exploded);

    if(isset($result) && count($result) != 0){
      $contactarray[] = $row2->contact_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're only checking if the result of `array_intersect` is set and that it contains more than 0 items. Other than that you're doing nothing with it... I'm guessing `tag_b` is in there, you're just not using it.

Comment: Sorry, reading my post again, I was not very clear....To provide more context, I've run several tests printing the contactarray and have applied various tag strings to those contacts and only the contacts who have have tag_a first (in the array) are being returned even though several other contacts have tag_a, though it's just not first in the array.

Comment: @Mischa had you truly paid attention by reformatting his code, you would've noticed the `$` sign I accidentally deleted.

Comment: @Fred, that's an edit on [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902170/php-html-dom-parse-all-links-recursively) that I have not touched. I am talking about the fact that you removed the indentation on **this question** which makes the question harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try array_uintersect()

Here $arr1 is your 1st array and $arr2 is second array

```
$intersect = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, 'compareDeepValue');
print_r($intersect);

function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['value'], $val2['value']);
}
```

This should give you both the values

Comment: Yea, I saw this in another thread, though when I try this I receive this error message: Message: array_uintersect() [function.array-uintersect]: Not a valid callback compareDeepValue

Comment: Try defining the compareDeepValue function above the $intersect = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, 'compareDeepValue');

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure where is the problem you are facing copy paste this code and you will see the two values properly.

```
$arr = array( 'tag_a','tab_b ');

$arr = array('tag_a','tab_b ');
print_r(array_intersect($arr, $arr));
```

Comment: Sorry, reading my post again, I was not very clear....To provide more context, I've run several tests printing the contactarray and have applied various tag strings to those contacts and **only** the contacts who have have tag_a first (in the array) are being returned even though several other contacts have tag_a, though it's just not first in the array.

Answer (score 0):

use master array for first argument and array to compare as second argument.
I am not sure what problem you have.